# Which ways to introduce a new variable in Scala exist?

Tags: scala, variable-declaration

It is well-known that a programmer can declare a new variable in Scala by using `val` or `var`, like this:

```
val x = 10 //x is now defined and an Integer.
```

A function parameter also introduces a new variable:

```
def fun(y: String) {
    //y of type String is now available here
}
```

These are straight forward examples. However, there are more ways to declare a variable in a given context.

For instance, a `match` expression can also introduce new variables:

```
val z = 10
z match {
     case w: Int => w //w is a valid variable of type Int in this scope
}
```

What are further commands which introduce variables into a certain scope in Scala?

*Background for the interested:*

I'm using this in a macro which finds variable definitions (ValDefs) in the abstract syntax tree. `match` expressions or function definitions generate a different syntax tree than normal ValDefs, which I have to take care of. Since I want my macro to be robust, I want to test it against all possible forms of variable declarations.

*Notes on comments:*

Method definitions with `def` are not of concern. Furthermore, I am only interested in variables which are visible in the source code and can be referenced by some term.

Comment: One thing I'm not sure about is anonymous functions, you could have a function with `def` that has some anonymous functions inside, those should also count has new variables I suppose.

Comment: I don't include functions defined with `def`. I do however include function parameters (also anonymous) or values of type `functionN`, e.g. `val fun = (x: Int) => x`. I can treat those the same way as I treat normal variables as far as I know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a list of everything I know of that might be different; `x` is the variable created:

```
// Within a block
val x = 5
var x = 5
lazy val x = 5
def x = 5
object x { val value = 5 }
val MyCaseClass(x, _) = oneOfMyCaseClasses
val MyCaseClass(_, Another(x)) = foo
val MyCaseClass(_, x @ Another(_)) = foo

// Functions
m.map( x => bar(x) )
m.map( (x: Int) => bar(x) )

// Functions that destructure
m.map{ case y if foo(y) => baz; case x => bar(x) }
m.map{ case Option(x) => bar(x) }
m.map{ case Option(List(x)) => bar(x) }
m.map{ case Option(x @ List(_)) => foo(x) }

// Partial functions with/without destructuring
m.collect{ case x => bar(x) }
m.collect{ case Option(List(x)) => bar(x) }
m.collect{ case Option(x @ List(_)) => foo(x) }

// For comprehensions
for (x <- xs)
for (y <- ys; x = foo(y))
for ((x, _) <- zs)
for ((_, y @ Option(_)) <- ws)

// Method arguments
def foo(x: Int) = 
def foo(y: Int)(implicit x: Foo) =
class Foo(x: Int)
class Foo(val x: Int)
class Foo(var x: Int)
case class Foo(x: Int)
case class Foo(var x: Int)
```

Comment: Since the question is about macros looking at ValDefs, how about `x$1` temporaries in `(1 to 10).toList indexOf (from=1, elem=5)` or similarly `(1 to 10).toList indexOf (_: Int, 1)`.

Comment: Well, there comes a lot of work! Awsome! Macro Temporaries (´x$1´ etc.) are no concern. Similar, `_` is ruled out. Basically I only care about variables which are also visible in the source code and can be referenced by some term.

Answer (score 1):

Destructuring Bind:

```
case class CaseClassFiftyThree(x: Double, y: Long, z: String)
...
someValue match { case CaseClassFiftyThree(x, y, z) =>
  /* x, y and z are bound here as Double, Long and String, resp. */ }
```

Irrefutable Pattern Match:

```
val (r, s, t) = (53, 17.0 * 3 + 2, "LIII")

/* r, s and t are bound here as Int, Double and String, resp. */
```